# Ninject ActivationException

Tags: ninject

I'm getting the infamous "Error activating XYZ. No matching bindings are available blah blah blah" from Ninject 3.0.1.10 in an ASP.NET MVC project.

The following is how I've setup my binding (very simple):

```
public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));

            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
            RegisterServices(kernel);

            return kernel;
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["STAGING"].ConnectionString;

            kernel.Bind<IUserAccountRepository>()
                  .To<SqlUserAccountRepository>()
                  .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);

            kernel.Bind<IRecipeRepository>()
                  .To<SqlRecipeRepository>()
                  .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", connectionString);

            kernel.Bind<HomeViewModel>().ToSelf();
        }
    }
```

When the controller Index action is invoked it attempts to create a HomeViewModel object as such:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IKernel      kernel = new StandardKernel();
    HomeViewModel model = kernel.Get<HomeViewModel>();

    ...
```

Which triggers the exception:

```
Error activating IRecipeRepository No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. 
Activation path: 
2) Injection of dependency IRecipeRepository into parameter recipeRepository of constructor of type HomeViewModel  
1) Request for HomeViewModel
```

But if I attempt to get an instance of HomeViewModel directly after calling kernel.Bind in RegisterServices then it works fine.

Here's what the HomeViewModel looks like (some details removed for sake of brevity):

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel(IRecipeRepository      recipeRepository,
                         IUserAccountRepository userAccountRepository)
    {
        this.recipeRepository = recipeRepository;
        this.userAccountRepository = userAccountRepository;
    }

    //
    // Some details removed for sake of brevity
    //

    private readonly IRecipeRepository      recipeRepository;
    private readonly IUserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;
}
```

Any idea what I'm missing? Why is the controller "special" in this case?

Comment: What does your HomeViewModel look like?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Ian. I've added the HomeViewModel.

Comment: It looks like CreateKernel is not getting called when I new up a StandardKernel in the controller. But if I change CreateKernel in App_Start to be public and call it directly from within the controller rather than new StandardKernel it works. So I'm getting warmer. I'm probably missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: It appears I need to explicitly supply a module to the StandardKernel constructor where the binding would take place in the Load override [demonstrated here](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2011/10/24/using-ninject-with-wcf-services/). I'll give that a try...

Comment: I think there is a bigger issue if your Start method isn't getting called to initialize the kernel. Did you use the ninject.mvc3 nuget package to get this set up?

Comment: Thank Ian, Start is getting called. I finally figured it out. I don't need to create instances using the kernel explicitly. I made an incorrect assumption based on examples I had read. Everything is working. Thanks again for looking at this.